# How to repeat on ABAQUS FEM simulations without reloading the mesh?

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, abaqus, feedback-loop

I would like to perform several FEM simulations on a given mesh with ABAQUS, where only the orientation of an element set would change in between.

Currently, I'm just generating several inp files (see an example below) and I run them one after the other. But this has the inconvenience to reload every time the mesh, which takes time due to its large size.

Would there be a way to load the mesh only once, perform the simulations, save the results in a file, modify the orientation (orientation label going from ORI_1 to ORI_X), reperform the simulation, save in another file and so on?

I thank you in advance,
Regards,
R.B.

```
*HEADING
TEST
*INCLUDE,INPUT=Mesh.inp
*INCLUDE,INPUT=PARAMETERS_MATRIX.inp
*Solid Section, elset=AllE, material=Matrix, ORIENTATION=Matrix
*INCLUDE,INPUT=PARAMETERS_CRYSTAL.inp
*INCLUDE,INPUT=ORIENTATIONS_LIST.inp
*Solid Section, elset=MID, material=CRYSTAL, ORIENTATION=ORI_123

*Step, NLGEOM=NO, name=Step-1
*Static 
1., 1, 1e-05, 1.
*INCLUDE,INPUT=MESH_BC.inp
*Output, field
*element output, POSITION=CENTROIDAL, elset=AllE
S,E,EVOL
*End Step
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be creating *`n`* no of input files with orientation corresponding to *`orientation_i`* with the help of some programming language and run all of them as a batch either with a simple python script or directly in the command prompt.

For example the python script would be,

> myJob1 = mdb.JobFromInputFile(<jobName>, <inputFile_i>)
>   myJob1.submit()
>   myJob1.waitForCompletion()

Repeating this *`n`* of times as required save as a python script and run it inside Abaqus CAE.

Or in command prompt,

> abaqus job=<inputFile_i> interactive

over *`n`* times

Another way would be using `*PARAMETER` keyword available in Abaqus.

For more information, look at PARAMETER keyword and JobFromInputFile in abaqus documentation.